# Spark Structured Streaming and Spark-Ml Regression

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

Is it possible to apply Spark-Ml regression to streaming sources? I see there is `StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD` but It's for older RDD API and I [couldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248959/consume-spark-sql-dataset-as-rdd-based-job) use It with structured streaming sources.

1. How I'm supposed to apply regressions on structured streaming sources?
2. (A little OT) If I cannot use streaming API for regression how can I commit offsets or so to source in a batch processing way? (Kafka sink)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today (Spark 2.2 / 2.3) there is no support for machine learning in Structured Streaming and there is no ongoing work in this direction. Please follow [SPARK-16424](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16424) to track future progress.

You can however:

- Train iterative, non-distributed models using forEach sink and some form of external state storage. At a high level regression model could be implemented like this:

  - Fetch latest model when calling `ForeachWriter.open` and initialize loss accumulator (not in a Spark sense, just local variable) for the partition.
  - Compute loss for each record in `ForeachWriter.process` and update accumulator.
  - Push loses to external store when calling `ForeachWriter.close`.
  - This would leave external storage in charge with computing gradient and updating model with implementation dependent on the store.
- Try to hack SQL queries (see https://github.com/holdenk/spark-structured-streaming-ml by [Holden Karau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572083/holden))

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate more about forEach method? As I understand It's a method to do some action (like writing to db) on each `Row`. But for applying regression I need to do some action (training and evaluating) on a dataset.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll give up with streaming API since by *external storage which computes gradients* I feel I won't get any help from spark-ml.

Comment: True, although it might sound more serious than it is. After all with GD it is just a one line with any decent linear algebra lib. But if you're looking for built-in support in Structured Streaming there is none at the moment.