# AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm receiving an exception which indicates that I need to start a stream in order to use it. However, the stream is being started. What's wrong with this setup?

```
spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServers)
  .option("subscribe", "inputTopic")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load
  .selectExpr(deserializeKeyExpression, deserializeValueExpression)
  .select("value.*")
  .withColumn("date", to_timestamp(from_unixtime(col("date"))))
  .transform(model.transform)
  .select(col("id") as "key", func(col(config.probabilityCol)) as "value.prediction")
  .selectExpr(serializeKeyExpression, serializeValueExpression)
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("update")
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServers)
  .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
  .option("topic", "outputTopic")
  .start
```

Here's the exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
kafka
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$$anonfun$checkForBatch$1.apply(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126)
    ...
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$foreachUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.checkForBatch(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertSupported(QueryExecution.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData(QueryExecution.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2491)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.first(Dataset.scala:2498)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.first$lzycompute$1(VectorAssembler.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.org$apache$spark$ml$feature$VectorAssembler$$first$1(VectorAssembler.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$1.apply$mcI$sp(VectorAssembler.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:88)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$2.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$2.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.flatMap(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.transform(VectorAssembler.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(Pipeline.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(Pipeline.scala:306)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.transform(Pipeline.scala:306)
    at com.company.project.Stream$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(NewsRateJob.scala:65)
    at com.company.project.Stream$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(NewsRateJob.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.transform(Dataset.scala:2513)
    at com.company.project.Stream.transform(NewsRateJob.scala:65)
    at com.company.project.Stream.setupStream(NewsRateJob.scala:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

I'm familiar with the issues of spark 2.2 and the VectorAssembler, however I am using spark 2.3.1.

Comment: Try narrowing down where the problem occurs. If you remove the `transform(model.transform)` part, does it work as expected?

Comment: @Shaido yes, the exception occurs on `model.transform`. It doesn't quite work as expected because `model.transform`, well, transforms the dataset into a different type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception occurred because the model was trying to access the data from the stream before the stream was started. In this case, the VectorAssembler was calling `first` on the dataset in order to determine how wide the vector is.

2.3 does not automatically fix problems with the VectorAssembler and structured streaming, it simply provides a class (specifically the VectorSizeHint class) which can be used in conjunction with the VectorAssembler with structured streaming. Adding this to the stages of the pipeline fixed the problem.

```
stages += new VectorSizeHint()
  .setInputCol(column)
  .setSize(size)
```

Here's some documentation which shows how it can be used: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/mllib/mllib-pipelines-and-stuctured-streaming.html

Note: this is not required for the OneHotEncoderEstimator feature.

We experienced similar stack traces for a couple other reasons. One was caused because we were using a OneHotEstimator in our model (that needed to be updated to a OneHotEncoderEstimator), the other was caused because we were caching the pipeline (we removed the cache step).

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs because you are trying to use ML `Transformer` with streaming `Dataset`. As explained in [Spark Structured Streaming and Spark-Ml Regression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48249017), as of today, Spark doesn't support ML on structured streams.

You'll have to rewrite your code to manually transform the data without dependency on RDDs and ML library.

Comment: I'm not sure what that Jira ticket references, here's some databricks documentation showing how to use MLlib pipelines and structured streaming. https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/mllib/mllib-pipelines-and-stuctured-streaming.html