# How to transform structured streams with PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

This seems like it should be obvious, but in reviewing the docs and examples, I'm not sure I can find a way to take a structured stream and transform using PySpark.

For example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName('StreamingWordCount')
    .getOrCreate()
)

raw_records = (
    spark
    .readStream
    .format('socket')
    .option('host', 'localhost')
    .option('port', 9999)
    .load()
)

# I realize there's a SQL function for upper-case, just illustrating a sample
# use of an arbitrary map function
records = raw_records.rdd.map(lambda w: w.upper()).toDF()

counts = (
    records
    .groupBy(records.value)
    .count()
)

query = (
    counts
    .writeStream
    .outputMode('complete')
    .format('console')
    .start()
)
query.awaitTermination()
```

This will throw the following exception:

```
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start
```

However, if I remove the call to `rdd.map(...).toDF()` things seem to work fine.

Seems as though the call to `rdd.map` branched execution from the streaming context and causes Spark to warn that it was never started?

Is there a "right" way to apply `map` or `mapPartition` style transformations using Structured Streaming and PySpark?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every transformation that is applied in Structured Streaming has to be fully contained in `Dataset` world - in case of PySpark it means you can use only `DataFrame` or SQL and conversion to `RDD` (or `DStream` or local collections) are not supported.

If you want to use plain Python code you have to use `UserDefinedFunction`.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf
def to_upper(s)
    return s.upper()

raw_records.select(to_upper("value"))
```

See also [Spark Structured Streaming and Spark-Ml Regression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48249017)

Answer (score 0):

Another way for a specific column (column_name):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def to_uper(string):
    return string.upper()

to_upper_udf = udf(to_upper,StringType())

records = raw_records.withColumn("new_column_name"
                      ,to_upper_udf(raw_records['column_name']))\
                      .drop("column_name")
```