# Building Spark ML pipeline model from structured streaming DataFrame using Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-science, apache-spark-ml

I am very new in Data Science, looking for some help.

I want to build Spark ML pipeline model from structured streaming DataFrame, but getting some error. Please see below the code snippet and error message.

Note : We have trained our model offline just want to build scoring model from structured streaming DataFrame.

**Code:**

```
pipelineModel= PipelineModel.load('/model/path/')
scoringDf = pipelineModel.transform(streamingDf)
```

**Error Message:**

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1910.transform.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
Kafka
```

We are using DSE Cassandra v 6.0, which has Spark 2.2.1. So anyone cal advice the issues with transforming a pre-trained PipelineML object onto streaming dataframes in **Spark 2.2**?

Please provide me some input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Structured Streaming and Spark-Ml Regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249017/spark-structured-streaming-and-spark-ml-regression)

Answer (score -1):

You are attempting to transform before the streaming ends. Streaming is a bit of a different concept, here you are assuming you are working on batch data where you complete everything in one step.

Try waiting the end of the streaming computation by adding your-streaming-context-variable.awaitTermination() right before you call the transform method.

You can read [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) to get an understanding of streaming computation of Spark.

Comment: How can the code be changed in order to resolve that error message?

Comment: Before you call the transform function as I explained in my answer. In this example, before the line scoringDf = pipelineModel.transform(streamingDf), call awaitTermination() function on your streaming context variable.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet that shows how to fix this problem? His code is pretty concise - it could be what you are saying but it could also be a few other problems (using the a VectorAssembler or a OneHotEncoder in the pipeline). Adding a code snippet will help him to test out whether or not your answer is correct